# ASP.NET MVC Identity 2.2.1 how to figure out why persistent authorization doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I configured my authentication like in MVC template with authorization. 
I want my system to never log out users once logged in. (persistent authorization)
But after each application restart users need to log in again. (My app is currently not optimized so I can get my application restarted easily with frequent opening a lot of tabs with the main page)
How can I approach this issue?

Code: 
Config.cs

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

App_Start/Config.Auth.cs

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            { 
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                    validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });

    }
```

App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs

```
 public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = false
        };
        manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
        };
        return manager;
    }
}
public class ApplicationSignInManager : SignInManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationSignInManager(ApplicationUserManager userManager, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        : base(userManager, authenticationManager)
    {
    }

    public override Task<ClaimsIdentity> CreateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUser user)
    {
        return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync((ApplicationUserManager)UserManager);
    }

    public static ApplicationSignInManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationSignInManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(), context.Authentication);
    }
}
```

Models/IdentityModels.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        return userIdentity;
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("name=MyDBContext")
    {
    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

And finally, login method of AccountController.cs

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your sign in code and any relevant configuration related to persistence.

Comment: Done! I did more research and it's still absolutely unclear for me why it doesn't work  and how I can debug it.